# JSOUP: How to parse a html text that is not associated with any element

Tags: jsoup

Given this portion of html:

```html
<table width="99%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <a href="popup_info.cfm?story=3703" target="popup2" onclick="var hwin=window.open('', 'popup2', 'resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=620,height=450');"><strong>48-Hour Notice</strong></a>
      <br />
      <strong>News of Districtwide Interest</strong>
      <br />A 48-Hour Notice that the Bridgewater-Raritan Regional Board of Education’s Special Meeting – Policy on Wednesday, May 18, 2016 originally scheduled for 8:00 p.m. at the Harmon V. Wade Administration Building has been rescheduled to begin at 7:00
      p.m. &nbsp; Action may be taken. &nbsp;
      <br clear="all">
      <p></p>
      <br />
      <a href="popup_info.cfm?story=3578" target="popup2" onclick="var hwin=window.open('', 'popup2', 'resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=620,height=450');"><strong>Modified 2015-2016 School Calendar</strong></a>
      <br />Adamsville Primary, Bradley Gardens Primary, Crim Primary, Hamilton Primary, John F. Kennedy Primary, Milltown Primary, Van Holten Primary, Eisenhower Intermediate, Hillside Intermediate, Middle School, High School, Home Page Only
      <br />At their meeting on Tuesday, May 10, 2016, the Board of Education approved the modification of the 2015-2016 School Calendar to include Monday, June 13, 2016 as a day off for all students and staff. Please refer to the modified school calendar link
      below on our district website:modified school calendar&nbsp;
      <br clear="all">
      <p></p>
      <br />
      <a href="popup_info.cfm?story=3689" target="popup2" onclick="var hwin=window.open('', 'popup2', 'resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=620,height=450');"><strong>Teacher of the Year and Educational Services Professional Award Winners</strong></a>
      <br/>
      <strong>News of Districtwide Interest</strong>
      <br />Congratulations to our staff members who have been named to the 2015-2016 Bridgewater-Raritan Teacher of the Year Award and the 2015-2016 Educational Services Professional Award. &nbsp;These individuals were honored at the district’s Staff Reception,
      sponsored by the BREA, on Wednesday, May 4, at the High School. &nbsp;On behalf of the Board of Education, we thank them for their outstanding...
      <a href="popup_info.cfm?story=3689" target="popup2" onclick="var hwin=window.open('', 'popup2', 'resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=620,height=450');">
    more info</a> 
      <br clear="all">
      <p></p>
      <br />
```

How do I parse the text outside of the Strong tags as separate elements?

```
Elements news = doc.select("p:not[^]");
```

that only provides me with one giant element containing everything including those within in the Strong elements.

Ideally I would want the code to work as follows

```
Element 1:A
48-Hour Notice that the Bridgewater-Raritan Regional Board of Education’s Special
Meeting – Policy on Wednesday, May 18, 2016 originally scheduled for 8:00 p.m.
at the Harmon V. Wade Administration Building has been rescheduled to begin at
7:00 p.m. 

&nbsp;

Action
may be taken.

&nbsp;  
Element 2:Adamsville Primary, Bradley Gardens Primary, Crim Primary, Hamilton Primary, John F. Kennedy Primary, Milltown Primary, Van Holten Primary, Eisenhower Intermediate, Hillside Intermediate, Middle School, High School, Home Page Only<br />
At their meeting on Tuesday, May 10, 2016, the Board of Education approved the modification of the 2015-2016 School Calendar to include Monday, June 13, 2016 as a day off for all students and staff. Please refer to the modified school calendar link below on our district website:modified school calendar&nbsp;
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

> How to parse a html text that is not associated with any element

As of Jsoup 1.9.2, it's not possible with the [`Selector`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) class. 
So, your next option is to use directly the Jsoup API. Especially, you would use the `TextNode` class. This option requires too much work.

So the last option is to use the RSS feed of the website instead: http://www.brrsd.k12.nj.us/rss/News.xml. The information is well formated and far easier to parse. See the sample code below for more details.

> how do you find the XML pages for other websites?

You can find more RSS feed here: http://www.brrsd.k12.nj.us/newinfo.cfm.
Once you're on the page click on the "RSS Feeds" tab.

---

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class FetchRssFeed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String rssFeedUrl = "http://www.brrsd.k12.nj.us/rss/News.xml";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(rssFeedUrl).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();

        Elements items = doc.select("item");

        for (Element item : items) {
            String title = extractData(item, "title", "<NO TITLE>");
            String description = extractData(item, "description", "<NO DESCRIPTION>");

            if (description.endsWith("... (Continued)")) {
                // Fetch full description
                String newsUrl = extractData(item, "guid", null);
                description += " [UNABLE TO GET FULL DESCRIPTION]";

                if (newsUrl != null) {
                    Document news = Jsoup.connect(newsUrl).get();
                    Element newsContent = news.select("#content > table > tbody > tr > td").first();

                    if (newsContent != null) {
                        Elements tmp = newsContent.select("span.sw-newsHeader");
                        title = tmp.text();
                        tmp.remove(); // Remove title to get full description

                        description = newsContent.text();
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.format("Title: %s%nDescription: %s%n%n", title, description);
        }
    }

    private static String extractData(Element item, String dataName, String defaultValue) {
        Element data = item.select(dataName).first();
        String dataValue;

        if (data == null) {
            dataValue = defaultValue;
        } else {
            dataValue = data.text();
        }

        return dataValue;
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT (truncated)

```
Title: Daily Announcements 5-19-16
Description: 8th grade choir will practice TB47th gr band rehearses TB78th gr band rehearses TB5The school store will be open today during lunch, please stop by.

Title: 6th Grade UPENN Museum Trip, Thursday, May 19, 2016
Description: Students should arrive in the All Purpose Room between 6:45 and 7:00 am. Students should not bring school materials to school with them that day.(...)
(...)
```

Comment: I tried using the sample code you provided above. The problem is for some reason either no elements are being selected from the document. Even with both if/else statements filled out im receiving no feedback because the element array is null. Do you know why this is happening. Also on a side note, how do you find the XML pages for other websites?